# Showing a set is not maximally consistent.

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Working on the book by Dirk van Dalen. "*Logic and Structure (Universitext)*" (p. 46)

> **Definition 1.5.6** A set $\Gamma$ is *maximally consistent* iff
> (a) $\Gamma$  is consistent,
> (b) $\Gamma \subseteq \Gamma'$  and $\Gamma'$ consistent $\Rightarrow \Gamma = \Gamma'$.

Given set:

> $\Gamma = \{p_5 \to p_7, p_1 \lor p_5, p_5 \to (p_7 \to p_1), \lnot p_7 \lor \lnot p_1\} \cup \{p_8, p_9,...\}$

I suspect the given set is not *maximally consistent*.

- It is *consistent*, since I found a truth assigment $v$ where $v(\phi)=T$, for all $\phi \in \Gamma$, and defined as follows:
  $$
  v(p_5) = F\\
  v(p_7) = F\\
  v(p_1) = T
  $$
- It is not *maximally consistent*, since I found a set
  $$\Gamma'= \{p_5 \to p_7, p_1 \lor p_5, p_5 \to (p_7 \to p_1), \lnot p_7 \lor \lnot p_1\} \cup \{p_8, p_9,...\} \cup \{p_2\}
  $$ with $\Gamma \subseteq \Gamma'$ such that $\Gamma \neq \Gamma'$.

Questions:

- Is my proof and reasoning correct ?
- In which way does the value of $v(p_2)$ determines if the set is or isn't maximally consistent ?

Comment: YES: your example works. Adding $p_2$ we have a superset of $\Gamma$ that is still consistent.

Comment: Obviously we must have $v(p_i)=\text T$ for every $i \ge 8$ and also $v(p_2)=\text T$ for $\Gamma'$. The existence of $v$ that satisfies every formula in the set determines the consistency of the set. The maximality condition depends on the formulas in the set: in a nutshell, the set is "closed" with respect to satisfiability: adding a formula that is not already there will destroy consistency.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Mauro ALLEGRANZA ! So, in my list of valuations, I should include $v(p_2)=T$, right ?

Comment: One question if I may, @Mauro ALLEGRANZA. When they speak about the existence of a valuation that satisfies every formula in the set, are they referring to the theorem that says: "if a set of formulas $\Delta$ is satisfiable, then it is consistent" ? I ask because, as I see it, the notion of consistency has nothing to do with semantics; only with derivability. So, they look for a way to satisfy the set, and then invoke that theorem.

Comment: Exactly: consistency is syntactical while satisfiability is semantical and we have $\text {Cons}(\Gamma) \text {  iff  } \text {Sat}(\Gamma)$

Comment: See van Dalen, page 43: **Lemma 2.5.11** If $Γ$ is consistent, then there exists a valuation such that $v(\psi) = 1$ for all $\psi ∈ Γ$.

Comment: And see page 40: **Lemma 2.5.4** If there is a valuation such that $v(\psi) = 1$ for all $\psi ∈ Γ$ , then $Γ$ is consistent.

Comment: The two lemmas are crucial for proving (page 43) **Theorem 2.5.13** (Completeness Theorem) $Γ \vdash \phi \text {  iff  }  Γ \vDash \phi$.

Comment: Thank you, @Mauro ALLEGRANZA. That's interesting. Looking at Completeness Theorem, I see in the book it uses an "if and only if". I though Soundness was one way of the implication and Completeness, the other one. Is that correct ?

Comment: Correct........